# Creating random points from attribute field

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, random

In QGIS 3.6, I wanted to create different layers of random points reading different fields of an attribute table. For example:

```
City  #cinemas    #malls     #stores
A       15         10          12
B       20         21          10
C       16         20          16
```

If I have the layer for the map of the cities, how would I plot the distribution of cinemas, malls and stores as random points in each city. reading the values from this attribute table? Without inputting values myself though.

Comment: I suppose u want to scatter 15 cinemas, 10 malls and 12 stores in city A ? Is that your aim ? You should not call (imho) your table _"attribute table"_ since it's not an attribute table as usually understood in GIS terminology ... you want to create 3 layers with cinemas, malls and stores entities ... ? **please clarify** ...

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use tools which are present in QGIS (so no scripting) you can have a look at the `Random points inside a polygon`plug-in. Which can be found in `Vector --> Research Tools`. You need the boundaries for each city as a polygon layer.

Comment: Your suggestion does what I want without scripting. Thank you.

Comment: @user147799 If this answers your question the best way to say "Thank you" is to upvote and mark as the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: If this answers the question he should **entirely** rephrase it ...

Comment: @snaileater I agree, this was just a/my interpretation of the problem